# Sharing an Internet connection with VirtualBox

Tags: linux, usb, vmware, virtualization

I connect to the Internet using a WiMAX USB dongle. Sadly, the USB doesn't work on Linux.

Can I, in principle, use VMWare or Virtualbox to install and run a Windows machine from Linux and connect to the Internet using the USB from Windows and share it with the host OS Linux?

Comment: When you say "the USB doesn't work on Linux" are you saying that the USB ports don't work, or the USB dongle doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox allow sharing of USB devices. I've tried to connect devices to VM where host didn't had drivers without success.

As far as I've noticed both systems (host and guest) need the propper drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I was listening to the [Linux Outlaws podcast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Outlaws) today, and Fab mentioned that he used a Windows virtual machine to look after his iPhone because it wouldn't play with Linux.

Anyway, give it try, it's not going to cost anything.

I would guess that Windows will be able to connect to the Internet but that setting up the routing, so that Linux can use it, will be a bit of a pain.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this under Mac OSX but it was under parallels not V-box. it works but the networking is run under windows and is shared with OSX, it works but it is a funky setup.

I would also suggest looking on the Intel Open Source site as they have some of the code available if you want to try and hack some code to get it working